# SystemMemoryExceedsReservation

Tags: memory, nodes, limit

Hey what does this rule say?

```html
 expr: |
sum by (node) (container_memory_rss{id="/system.slice"}) > ((sum by (node) (kube_node_status_capacity{resource="memory"} - kube_node_status_allocatable{resource="memory"})) * 0.95)
    for: 15m
    labels:
severity: warning
```

We are receiving SNOW tickets, saying "System memory usage of 1.161G on  exceeds 95% of the reservation". But upon checking there is no memory spike, as a matter of fact node limits has crossed 131%.